# Error while copying from obj\debug to bin\debug. Exceed retry count

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-10

I am new to developing windows form application with C#, while building a sample C# application I am facing the given error. Tried cleaning and re-building the solution. But it didn't help.

Error :

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\MyApplicationName.exe" to "bin\debug\MyApplicationName.exe".Exceeded retry count of 10 failed.
>
> Unable to copy "obj\Debug\MyApplicationName.exe" to "bin\debug\MyApplicationName.exe".The process cannot use "bin\debug\MyApplicationName.exe" because it is being used by another process.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: "in use" seems to be the important part.  Do you have it open somehow?  Stuck open in processes, but not on screen, perhaps?  Reboot if all else fails.

Comment: @DonBoitnott sorry for late response, no the process does not remain open in the background. Yeah it works if I restart VS.